# CSS - Hide labels for n+2th divs

Tags: css

I have a structure like the following:

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="row1">
     <label>Label 1A</label>
     <input .../>
     <label>Label 1B</label>
     <input .../>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
     <label>Label 2A</label>
     <input .../>
     <label>Label 2B</label>
     <input .../>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
     <label>Label 3A</label>
     <input .../>
     <label>Label 3B</label>
     <input .../>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

but I would like to show the labels only for the first row. The structure is auto-generated and can't change it.
I tried using the *nth-child* selector

```
.group:nth-child(n+2) div>label
```

but doesn't work. Actually even .group:nth-child(n+2) doesn't manage to select the n+2 divs.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: please note I don't know the classes on the single rows (row1, row2, etc.) before the page is generated.

Comment: Have you tried hiding all the labels then setting the 1st one to show?

Comment: You need `nth-child(n+2)` *of* the `.group`, so it should be `.group :nth-child(n+2) label` (not the space before the `:`) or `.group div:nth-child(n+2) label`. Or another alternate would be to hide all at first and then just make `.group div:first-child label` as visible.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answers. I'll choose Sebastian because he was the first to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake on `.group:nth-child(n+2) div > label`. Remove the `div` because the `nth-child` select the `div`! If you need the space on the left side you can use `visibility:hidden;` to hide the `label` instead of removing the space with `display:none;`

**You can use the following solution:**

```css
.group div:nth-child(n+2) label  {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="row1">
     <label>Label 1A</label>
     <input .../>
     <label>Label 1B</label>
     <input .../>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
     <label>Label 2A</label>
     <input .../>
     <label>Label 2B</label>
     <input .../>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
     <label>Label 3A</label>
     <input .../>
     <label>Label 3B</label>
     <input .../>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the :not selector for this kind of thing, especially if you don't know how many rows you're going to be dealing with (you've mentioned that they're generated)

The nth-child selector can work, too. I've provided several examples of how to do this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEVOPL?editors=1100

This is the selector you were originally asking about, though:

```
.example2 .group div:nth-child(n+2) label{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

(edited out Opacity:0; for visibility:hidden;)

Comment: Great answer. I should have made clear that I don't know the row1, rows2... before the code is generated, so I cannot use **not(.row1)**

Comment: Alright, the `nth-of-type` or the `nth-child` selector examples will work fine for you, then :) Also, be sure to check out this link. Helps to simplify the selector ranging https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/. Also, you can always use :first-of-type in combination with the row divs containing these labels and inputs

Comment: That's an awesome link! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this, hide your label for .row2 and .row3. There are two ways that I have added i.e. either manual selecting of label from particular div or same as you asked n+2.

```
.row2 > label{
opacity:0;
}
.row3 > label{
opacity:0;
}
```

**(or)**

```
div:nth-child(n+2) label{
opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: I have an indefinite number of rows. The first part of your solution implies I would have to know the ids in advance and add them all in the CSS.

Comment: That's why I added that if you are planning for manual then above implies, but as you are working dynamically then at that point you could hide the opacity of label.